# ng2-pdf-viewer - does not display automatic pdf

Tags: angular, pdf

I have an angular application 8 that I receive a pdf file from the API.
In the angle view, I took the pdf file as a blob and converted it into a FileReader to use the byte array.
I am facing the following problem, the pdf only appears on the screen when I click on the page or scroll the screen. I have already tested several properties of ng2-pdf-viewr and nothing worked. I want the pdf to be displayed on the screen as soon as I upload it.
Can anyone help me with this problem?

component.html:

```
<pdf-viewer 
    [src]="fileReader.result" 
    style="display: block;">
</pdf-viewer>
```

component.ts:

```
private actionsForSuccessDownloadFile(data: any, tipo: string) {
      this.blob = new Blob([data], { type: tipo });

      // Blob -> ArrayBuffer
      this.fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.blob);
      this.loading = false; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Found a temporary fix. In component.html:

```
<pdf-viewer 
    [src]="fileReader.result" 
    style="display: block; min-height: 250px">
</pdf-viewer>
```

No need to be specific 250px

Comment: min-height: is necessary. without it pdf was not visible. Thanks Nerdya

Answer (score 0):

Another way to build PDF in Angular. Just have a look
https://www.pdftron.com/blog/angular/build-a-pdf-viewer-in-angular-and-pdf-js/